# How to Set integer from controller to Subview without calling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to set int value of count from my main-controller to data-cell controller file.
I dont want to call that data-cell controller file now i want to call that data-cell M controler file later but i want to set Count integer from my Main controller file so that when i call my data-cell file it take count integer which i set from my main-controller and use it.

My dataViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UIView *backgroundCoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
backgroundCoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.6];
toggleSwitch1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
toggleSwitch2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[self.view addSubview:backgroundCoverView];

// Add the 6 buttons and columns.
NSMutableArray *columnsMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
NSMutableArray *buttonsMutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {



    DataCell* app = (DataCell*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app MysetValue:6];

    DataColumn *column = [[DataColumn alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(86+i*124+(i>=3?100:0), 230, 110, 382)];
    column.cellsVisible = NO;
    if (i>0) {
        column.hidden = YES;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:column];
    [columnsMutable addObject:column];
```

// i am calling dataColumn Which is SubView class and From that dataColumn sub view class i call data cell class to populate cell into column

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    //self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mixBackgroundTile.png"]];
    // this commented line is used to display dotted background in percentage slider bar 

    // Add cells.
    NSMutableArray *mutableCells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:5];
    for (int i=4; i>=0; i--) {
        DataCell *cell = [[DataCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, i*(74+3), 109, 74)]; // data order fix
         //VSLDataCell *cell = [[VSLDataCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-90, i*(74+3), 109, 74)]; for left hand side cell

        [mutableCells addObject:cell];
        [self addSubview:cell];
    }
    cells = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableCells];  
}
return self;
 }
```

Now in datacell class I want to assign differnt image according to cell number and colum number so i want to know that which column i am now

Comment: One doesn't "call M files", this has nothing to do with files. I assume you want to communicate between two objects of different classes, is it that?

Comment: @H2CO3 yes i want to set columNumber variable which is in cell data.m from my mainController.m

Comment: Ok, this suggests that `DataCell`, as it's name suggests, is _not_ the app delegate. The app delegate is a very special object in Cocoa Touch, not just something you create. So making this property of the app delegate makes no sense. It's a property of the `DataCell` class.

Comment: @Rob Ok so is there any other way to pass int or Not?

Comment: This is not valid for a Stack Overflow question. We should move this into chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27014 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. You're written a method, `MysetValue` which is a bit redundant. When you synthesized your `columNumber` property, it writes a setter method for you, `setColumNumber`, that does this for you. Don't write your own setter if you don't need to.
2. If you have a property, `columNumber` that you've defined in your .h, and synthesized in your .m of your `AppDelegate` (or whatever you called your app delegate class), you can now set this property via:

   ```
   AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [app setColumNumber:6];
   ```

   or equivalently,

   ```
   AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   app.columNumber = 6;
   ```
3. Your `DataCell` class is, based upon your clarified answer, *not* an app delegate class, though. Apparently this is some `UIView` based class. You can define custom properties for this `DataCell` class, but you wouldn't access those properties via `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`. You're apparently saving these `DataCell` objects in an array called `cells`. So if you wanted to set the first cell's `columNumber` property, you could do something like:

   ```
   DataCell *cell = cells[0];
   [cell setColumNumber:6];
   ```
4. When I first read the question, I thought you were focusing on communication between classes about properties changing values, for which KVO is useful. But this is a more advanced topic and we shouldn't worry about that at this point. It's only going to lead to confusion for a new developer.

   <strike>As an aside, one of the advantages of using the automatically generated setters methods, is that it automatically conforms to Key-Value Observing (KVO). (If you write your own setters, you can also do the necessary coding to support KVO, but there's no reason to do so here; use the standard setter.) See the [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html). Bottom line, a class can register itself as an observer for changes in a property of another class.</strike>

---

If you'd like to see an example of how to use a property, consider this view subclass:

DetailView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// public interfaces belong here

@interface DetailView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger columnNumber; // column number set during initialization
@property (nonatomic)           NSInteger tapCount;     // a count of how many times we tapped on this

- (id)initWithColumnNumber:(NSInteger)column;           // interface for creating DetailView

@end
```

DetailView.m:

```
#import "DetailView.h"

@implementation DetailView

const CGFloat kWidth = 40.0f;
const CGFloat kMargin = 5.0f;
const CGFloat kHeight = 300.0f;

// create view, set column number, set frame according to column number

- (id)initWithColumnNumber:(NSInteger)column
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(kMargin + column * (kWidth + kMargin), kMargin, kWidth, kHeight);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        _columnNumber = column;
        _tapCount = 0;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I could then write a view controller that adds these views, but when you tap on one, it will `NSLog` the column number for us and tell us how many times we've tapped on it:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailView.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (NSInteger column = 0; column < 5; column++)
    {
        DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] initWithColumnNumber:column];
        [self.view addSubview:detailView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [detailView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    DetailView *detailView = (id)gesture.view;
    NSAssert([detailView isKindOfClass:[DetailView class]], @"%s: Not a DetailView: %@", __FUNCTION__, detailView);

    detailView.tapCount++;

    NSLog(@"%s: column number = %d; tapped %d times", __FUNCTION__, detailView.columnNumber, detailView.tapCount);
}

@end
```

Comment: I think you access Application Delegate with `[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` not the other classes. other classes should be accessed via NibName or alloc

Comment: @nsgulliver How you reference the other object is clearly a function of how ever you created it. I assumed that despite the confusing name, that `DataCell` was his app delegate class. If not, yes, you're quite right that he reference that class however he created it.

Comment: @rob how can i use automatically setter method to set my columNumber

Comment: I think he has mentioned in his statement `DataCell` controller file, but anyhow his provided information is very much vague and confusing.

Comment: I will edit my Main question so you will get all information

Comment: @SwapAndroid If you've defined this property in the .h file for the class for which it is a property, any other class that gets a reference to it can just invoke the setters like my point #2 above. This is one of the key purposes in having `@property` statements, that these getter and setter interfaces are done automatically for you.

Comment: @SwapAndroid See [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DeclaredProperty.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH13-SW1) in the _Cocoa Core Competencies_ guide.

Comment: @Rob Do you have sample example which is used to create custom properties. by using that i can pass my int value from UIViewController class to UIView class

Comment: @SwapAndroid I've added a very simple example. One property that is `readonly` (the column number is `readonly` because you set it during initialization, but the view controller can't change it after the fact) and one that is read write (the `tapCount` is incremented by the view controller every time a user taps on it). This demonstrates initializing of a `readonly` property, retrieving property values, and updating a property value.

Comment: @Rob i dont want to create any button click like here you have used DetailView *detailView = (id)gesture.view; you used tap gesture but i want to call detail view.countNumber++ with in view-did-load
Like this 
for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {// for loop to create column 
        
        VSLDataCell *detailView = (id)gesture.view;// what i used here instead of (id)gesture.view to increment columNumber
        detailView.columnNumber++;
        
  VSLDataColumn *column = [[VSLDataColumn alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(86+i*124+(i>=3?100:0), 230, 110, 382)];

Comment: @SwapAndroid let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27085/discussion-between-rob-and-swapandroid)

Answer (score 0):

Move your  `MysetValue` to `AppDelegate` If you want to call it using appDelegate

```
AppDelegate* appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appdelegate MysetValue:6];
```

Comment: Ok i i put MysetValue method into app delegate than how can i fetch that value from app delegate to my data cell.m ? sorry to ask you but i am new to objective c

Comment: Is your `cell` subclass of `UITableViewCell` or `UIViewController`?